# Hours and minutes to hours value with fractional part

Tags: java, date, hour, minute

I have a form which calculates hours and mins between to times. I would like to convert result to value for calculating like 1hour 30 mins is result 1,5. Now I am getting result 1,3. I need to calculate at the moment and write it.

I found some converters but it doesnt calculate at the moment so it is not good for what I need.

I also want to user see hours and mins like my code shows. I know I could only split seconds with 0,6 but then show in select option 0,25 instead 0,15. Thats not an option.

- Ura pričetka - start time,
- Ura končanja - end time,
- Nadure - it is just calculating the value over a certain value,
- Ure - result which have to be calculated and converted at the moment

I am calculating in java.

Code:

```
 <td align="left">Ure </td>
            <td align="left"><input name="ure" id="ure" type="text" onchange="updatesum()"/></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th align="right">Ura pričetka </th>
            <td align="left"><select name="urap" id="urap" type= "time" onChange="updatesum()" value="9.00"/>
            <OPTION>
            <?php for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=15) // the interval for mins is '15'

        echo '<option>'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'.'
                       .str_pad($mins,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'
                       </option>'; ?></OPTION></td>
            <td align="left">Nadure </td>
            <td align="left"><input name="nadure" id="nadure" type="text" onchange="updatesum()"  /></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th align="right">Ura končanja </th>

            <td align="left"><select name="urak" id="urak" type= "time" onChange="updatesum()" value=""/>

            <OPTION>

            <?php for($hours=0; $hours<24; $hours++) // the interval for hours is '1'
    for($mins=0; $mins<60; $mins+=15)  
     // the interval for mins is '15'

        echo '<option>'.str_pad($hours,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT).'.'
                       .str_pad($mins ,2,'0',STR_PAD_RIGHT).'
                       </option>';                    
                       ?>
            </OPTION>     
            </td> 




       <script type="text/javascript">

       function updatesum() {


document.loginForm.ures.value = (document.loginForm.urak.value -0) - (document.loginForm.urap.value -0);
$ures = loginForm.ures.value;
if (loginForm.ures.value > <?php echo $test ?>) {
  loginForm.ure.value ='<?php echo $test ?>'
  loginForm.nadure.value = (document.loginForm.ures.value -0) - (document.loginForm.ure.value -0);
}

if (loginForm.ures.value <= <?php echo $test ?>) {
  loginForm.ure.value = loginForm.ures.value
  loginForm.nadure.value = (document.loginForm.ures.value -0) - (document.loginForm.ure.value -0);
}

};

</script>

            <input type="text" name="ures" onChange="updatesum()"/>
```

Comment: What on Earth does Java have to do with your question?

Comment: I am calculating in java. I am not real expert so sorry if I make any mistake.

Comment: I’m not sure whether your PHP code is helpful or not. You may want to either convey the important information from it in a shorter form, or if you think it’s worth including, then at least indent nicely so we can read it without too much strain.

Comment: By the way, decimal fractions is a poor way to represent a span of time. Consider using text per the [ISO 8601 standard for durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations). The *java.time* classes `Period` and `Duration` use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

Comment: @BasilBourque For the sake of completeness only, according to your link “The smallest value used may also have a decimal fraction, as in "P0.5Y" to indicate half a year.” So `PT1,5H` is accepted as one and a half hours in ISO 8601 (though the `Duration` class of Java cannot parse nor generate it). I’ll let the asker decide whether fractional hours are really required in his/her web app.

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion could be:

```
    String startTimeString = "08:30";
    String endTimeString = "10:00";

    LocalTime startTime = LocalTime.parse(startTimeString);
    LocalTime endTime = LocalTime.parse(endTimeString);
    long totalMinutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(startTime, endTime);
    double hours = (double) totalMinutes / (double) Duration.ofHours(1).toMinutes();
    System.out.println("Hours between start and end: " + hours);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> Hours between start and end: 1.5

### Can I use this on Android?

[A duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645880/difference-of-2-dates-in-the-format-of-decimal) asked for this calculation on Android. It works nicely on older and newer Android devices.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the new classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To convert minutes to an hours decimal you would simply divide the minutes by 60

e.g 1:30 = 1 + (30/60) = 1.5

or :15 = 15/60 = 0.25

```
public static double methodName(int hours, int minutes) {
   return hours + (minutes / 60);
}
```

Comment: I know that as I mentoned in my post. But how can I do this in java so it will calculate in my result. Just cant find right way to do this in my code.

Comment: Create a method which takes hours and minutes, and returns the result of that calculation